# Cant store a list of pyserial Serial objects in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

To start off, Python is not my most used language so if there are any glaring mistakes please let me know of them.

My problem: I am trying to open 18 Serial ports/connections. I need to then loop through each of the connections to send data to each port. Right now I have the following method of storing the serial connections.

```
serialPortlist = []
serialPortList.append(Serial('PORTNAME', BAUDRATE, PARITY, STOPBITS, TIMEOUT))
```

I then repeat the second line 17 more times and append each one to the list.

When it comes time to access the ports I would have assumed I could just do a loop like the one below:

```
for port in serialPortList:
    port.reset_input_buffer()
    header = port.read(2)
```

When I run the above I get the error: Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

I just want to be able to iterate through a list or array or something. If not this is going to be a super painful project.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing the list after appending the items to see that they've been added correctly? Also you have a typo, you're initializing the list as serialPortlist but then appending to serialPortList (with a capital 'L'). Your error message indicates that the value of serialPortList is None

Comment: *I then repeat the second line 17 more times and append each one to the list*. How are you doing that? That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: Include your imports, where is `Serial` from.

Comment: I dont think you are in the same scope ... so where ever you are, `serialPortList` does not exist... @TrentonMcKinney im sure its `from serial import Serial`

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is almost certainly a scope issue ... wherever you have defined serialPortList, is not visible to the place you are trying to iterate it ... instead it has some default value of `None` or something (**for sure** `serialPortList == None` at the place you are encountering an error)

you can prove this easily

```
myList = []
for port in ["COM1","COM2"]:
    myList.append(serial.Serial(port))

#directly below where we instanciated it
for port in myList:  # no problems here :)
    port.write("some payload\n") # assuming \n is the terminator
    print(port.readline()) # assuming \n is the terminator
```

my guess is you are doing something like

```
myList = None
def initializeList():
    myList = []
    for port in ["COM1","COM2"]:
        myList.append(serial.Serial(port))

def someOtherFunction():
    for port in myList: # ERROR  myList is None!!!!
        ...

    
initializeList()
someOtherFunction()
```